# How to structure (save / retrieve) when needing to filter users's posts based on certain key?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

I'm building an app where the user can see posts that are specific to some key. Like, if they want to see posts about restaurants, they get posts about restaurants. How do I structure this?

Right now, every time a user posts something, there is a general `posts` node, and every post is saved under it, for all users.

So, how would I tell Firebase, "Only get these certain posts, from under that node?" One issue is: I don't want the posts to have to save what they are about, i.e., there isn't a key value pair like `restaurant : joe's pizza` inside the post.

Rather, I'm thinking of having topical nodes (`topics`), and then the reference to the post saved underneath that. So, say, node `Pizza` has 3 children underneath, all have the key that matches the key of the post (again, posts are saved in a separate node, where they store their data, the text and image.). And, say, node `Ice Cream` has 4 children - references to 4 posts about ice cream. So if I'm a user, and I want to see the posts about ice cream, I need Firebase to ask, "Hey, find that `Ice Cream` node, and then retrieve all the references underneath, and then grab the posts for each of those references, based on their keys."

Does that question make sense?

I would really appreciate any help. (I'm a new coder, and I've learned the most when other people answer questions I have). Thanks!

Comment: You can try [indexing](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/structure-data#fanout) in the structuring data guide Michael mentioned, replacing "groups" with "topics" in your case. You could store a "topics" value for each post (ex: topic: Pizza), then store references to the posts about Pizza in its respective "topic" node.

Answer (score 1):

To use Firebase optimally you definitely need to think intelligently about how to structure your data. Many best practices can be found [in the structuring data guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/structure-data). The key takeaways:

1. Try to structure your data similarly to how people will view it.
2. If you do need to slice and dice, you can only do this on one property at a time. For everything else, you will need to denormalize.
3. Fetching multiple nodes from Firebase isn't all that expensive -- because there's an open two-way socket connection, you can make many fetches quickly.

Ultimately you'll need to carefully plan your data structure for your application's specific needs.

Comment: I've figured out how to structure the data, but now, I'm trying to set up a backend server for FCM (to server my Firebase app). Do you know how I would do that? I've gone through their docs and here is what they leave out: How is the data containing the user-device tokens structured? How is it accessed and used? How do I talk to the server from the Firebase Client Side App? (I can connect to FCM, as the docs show, but it doesn't say what to do after that).

Comment: You need to take the token that you get by registering FCM on the client and put the returned registration ID somewhere a server can access it (the Realtime Database worksfor this). Then you can use the Firebase Admin SDK to send messages to the registered ID.